# Assign selected values to Pandas Series using dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a dataframe and want to over-write one of the rows with new values stored in a series of separate dictionaries.

Here is a similar setup of what I am talking about:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = {'A': range(3), 'B': range(3, 0, -1), 'C': [4, 0, 2]}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  3  4
1  1  2  0
2  2  1  2    # Let's say I want to put the new values in this row.

In [5]: d1 = {'A': 1, 'C': 1}

In [6]: d2 = {'B': 2}
```

Desired result:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  3  4
1  1  2  0
2  1  2  1
```

Basically, I need a way to get the values from multiple dictionaries inserted into a Pandas Series.

What I've tried:

```
In [15]: df.loc[2, :] = d1

In [16]: df.loc[2, :] = d2
```

(Doesn't work)

```
In [24]:     def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts):
    ...:         """Merges the dictionaries into one."""
    ...: 
    ...:         new_dict = list_of_dicts[0].copy()
    ...:         for e in list_of_dicts[1:]:
    ...:             new_dict.update(e)
    ...:         return new_dict
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [25]: merge_dicts([d1, d2])
Out[25]: {'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}

In [26]: df.loc[2, :] = merge_dicts([d1, d2])
```

(Works, but must be an easier way)

Note, I am using Python 3.4 or lower so the following is not possible:

```
In [10]: df.loc[2,:] = {**d1, **d2}
```

UPDATE:

Another sub-par solution:

```
In [9]: pd.Series(d1).combine_first(pd.Series(d2)).combine_first(df.loc[2, :])
Out[9]: 
A    1.0
B    2.0
C    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I just check your solution and I think need `pd.Series(d1).combine_first(pd.Series(d2)).combine_first(df.loc[2, :])` - last `combine_first` is here redundant, but is necessary if first `combine_first` return Series with missing some indexes of row 2 (columns names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is possible use `update` in loop:

```
result = {}
for d in [d1, d2]:
    result.update(d)

df.loc[2,:] = result
```

Or generator converted to dict:

```
df.loc[2,:] = dict(pair for d in [d1, d2] for pair in d.items())
```

Or dict comprehension:

```
df.loc[2,:] = {k: v for d in [d1, d2] for k, v in d.items()}
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  3  4
1  1  2  0
2  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
df.loc[2,:] = reduce(pd.Series.combine_first, [pd.Series(d) for d in d1, d2])
```

Works if the contents of d1, d2 are mutually exclusive.

I timed it though and it is not as fast as @jezrael's solutions.